# Build association while initializing to satisfy delegates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delegates, associations, activeadmin

I have this minimal example model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  delegate :name, prefix: true, to: author

  after_initialize { author ||= Author.new } 
end
```

After posting form data my framework (yes, ActiveAdmin) does this: `Book.new {author_name: 'Some Dude'}` which results in `author_name` not being written since the `after_initialize` callback is only called after initialization of `Book`.

How can I build the association "before" or "while" initializing? Any good pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the initialize method and call super:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  delegate :name, prefix: true, to: author

  def initialize(*args)
     author ||= Author.new
     super 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Sounds good and this is probably the only viable solution. But while googling I found that overriding `initialize` is discouraged as ActiveRecord sometimes would not initialize an objects the standard way.

Comment: you're not overriding it, as you call super. Which means that you are doing something and then saying, go do what you were going to do anyway

Comment: Yeah, but `initialize` might not be called under some circumstances is what I have read.

Comment: You could technically override new, instead of initialize, which would do the same thing. Be careful though, and test your code...

Comment: I was referring to this article: http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html -- I haven't checked if AR has changed since then. It probably has and for my use case I think you solution should be fine. THANKS!